# Do not understand formulation of Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I'm having issue with an exercise, I have the answer given but I don't quite follow it. The question is as follows:

Let α ∈ **R** \ {1}, I ⊂ **R** an interval and *p, q*: I → **R** continuous.
Show that y : I → (0, ∞) is a positive solution of the Bernoulli differential equation

$$y' + py = qy^{\alpha}$$

if and only if $y = w^{\frac{1}{1-\alpha}}$ where $w$: I → (0, ∞)is a positive solution of the linear differential equation

$$w' + (1 - \alpha)pw = (1-\alpha)q$$

The first part of the answer is given as

Let $y$ be a positive solution of the Bernoulli equation, and set $w := y^{1−α}$; then

$$w' = (1-\alpha)y^{-\alpha}y' - (1 -\alpha){\frac{w}{y}}(qy^\alpha - py) = (1 - \alpha)(q - pw) $$
so
$$w' + (1 - \alpha)pw = (1-\alpha)q$$

I unsertand the algebra of how $(1-\alpha)y^{-\alpha}y' - (1 -\alpha){\frac{w}{y}}(qy^\alpha - py) = (1 - \alpha)(q - pw)$, and how this becomes $w' + (1 - \alpha)pw = (1-\alpha)q$.

However, I simply don't know *how* $w' = (1-\alpha)y^{-\alpha}y' - (1 -\alpha){\frac{w}{y}}(qy^\alpha - py)$ is formulated in the first place.

**EDIT**

I believe there was an error in the answer given, it should be $$w' = (1-\alpha)y^{-\alpha}y' = (1 -\alpha){\frac{w}{y}}(qy^\alpha - py),$$ NOT
$$w' = (1-\alpha)y^{-\alpha}y' - (1 -\alpha){\frac{w}{y}}(qy^\alpha - py)$$

Answer (score 1):

It is formulated by substituting $w = y^{1 - \alpha}$ into your first ODE.

By the Chain Rule, we get:
$$
w' = (1 - \alpha) y^{-\alpha} y',
$$
so 
$$
y' = {1 \over 1 - \alpha} y^{\alpha} w'.
$$
and the left-hand side becomes:
$$
{1 \over 1 - \alpha} y^{\alpha} w' + p w^{1 \over 1 - \alpha},
$$
and the right-hand side becomes
$$
q \left( w^{1 \over 1 - \alpha} \right)^{\alpha}.
$$
Now solve the obtained equation for $w'$.

Comment: I did try that, and rearranged $w = y^{1-\alpha}$ to obtain $y^{\alpha}=\frac{y}{w}$, so $$w' =(1-\alpha) \frac{w}{y}(qy^a - py)$$ which is the wrong sign and missing $(1-\alpha)y^{-\alpha}y'$